# Getting UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning even when catching exceptions

Tags: node.js, promise, unhandled-promise-rejection

In NodeJS, I have some code like this:

```
function doSomethingAsync() {
    return Promise.reject("error");
}

function main() {
    doSomethingAsync().catch();
}
```

When I run this code, I get an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

I know that making my calling function `async` and `await`ing `doSomethingAsync` inside of a `try`/`catch` makes the error go away, but in this case, I don't want to add the extra complexity of making the function async and awaiting just to mute an error, so I'd prefer to use `catch()`.

Why doesn't my method of error handling mute the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.catch()` isn't actually catching anything.

If we look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch#return_value):

> Internally calls `Promise.prototype.then` on the object upon which it was called, passing the parameters `undefined` and the received `onRejected` handler.

*specs found [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-promise.prototype.catch)*

If we then look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#parameters) for `Promise.then`, we find:

> `onRejected`: A `Function` called if the `Promise` is rejected. This function has one argument, the `rejection reason`. **If it is not a function, it is internally replaced with a "Thrower" function** (it throws an error it received as argument).

So doing `.catch()` will not actually catch anything and your app will continue throwing an error. You have to pass a function to `catch()`.

Doing this will mute the error:

```
doSomethingAsync().catch(() => { });
```

Updating to say that this is actually called out [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) at the top of the page, but I just missed it.